# Get user input as they type JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

What I have is a form that is supposed to calculate tax. I'm using the `clone()` JavaScript functionality, but I'm having a bit of an issue. For instance if I store my basic salary and primary tax like this:

> Basic salary $5000
>
> Primary Tax $50

Below this is a row (`newtaxrow`) with an input that takes the field to be cloned, and a button, with id `clonetax`.
So the JavaScript:

```
$("#clonetax").click(function() {

        $("#newtaxrow:last").clone(true).insertAfter("#newtaxrow:last");
        $("#newtaxrow:last").find( ":input" ).val( "0" );
        $("#newtaxrow:last").find( ":input" ).change(dave()); 
});
```

The method `dave()`:

```
function dave() {

    var val1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('salary').innerText);
    var val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('tax').value);
    var val3 = parseInt(document.getElementById('newtaxfield').value);
    var total = val1 - (val2 + val3);
    document.getElementById("net").innerHTML = total;
}
```

So in essence, I need to total or sum up the values of the cloned fields on the fly. It won't work for the cloned fields, I know I'm doing something wrong... . Any assistance?

Comment: Protip: use parseInt(val, 10) - why? Try parseInt("08")

Comment: Also: $("#newtaxrow:last").find( ":input" ).change(dave()); change to $("#newtaxrow:last").find( ":input" ).change(dave);

Comment: if `dave` is your onchange-handler, then pass it as a function to `.change` (e.g. `.change(dave)`). Currently you are passing the *return value* of `dave` to `change` (you're executing the `dave()`).

Comment: @Misiur, I tried `parseInt("08")` and I got `8`, whats the problem with it?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko - depending on javascript engine you will get 0 instead of 8 (firefox using spidermonkey for example). The second argument is base which will be used to determine the value of string, if it is not provided it then is guessed. For "08" the base guessed is octal, which is correct, but not if you want decimal value.

Comment: in fucntion dave() why aren't you using jquery selectors?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko:
parseInt("13") parsed "13" based on the decimal system. (13 = 1*10^1 + 3*10^0 = 1*10 + 3*1 = 13)
parseInt("13",8) = 1*8^1 + 3*8^0 = 1*8 + 3*1 = 8+3 = 11.
If the number starts with a 0, it's parsed based on the octal system:
parseInt("08") = parseInt("08",8) = 0*8^1 + 8*8^0 = 0+8 = 8
If it starts with 0x, its hexadecimal: parseInt(... , 16)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.change(dave())
```

should be

```
.change(dave)
```

or

```
.change(function() { dave(); })
```

Comment: thanks for the replies, but the main problem is totaling the values of the cloned elements. any tips on how to go about that?

Comment: getElementById means that you look up for a single element. If you are after more than one salary field, then you may want to define css classes and use $(".salary") and then use a loop to add up all the salary values

Comment: Assuming you have assigned a css class 'taxfield' to all taxfields in your ui, cloned or not. var sum = 0; $('.taxfield').each(function() { sum += $(this).val()})

Comment: totalothertax = 0;
            $('#newtaxfield').focusout(function() {
               $( ".newtaxfield" ).each(function( index ) {
                    totalothertax += parseInt($(this).val());
                });
                alert(  "total::" + totalothertax);
                console.log(  "total::" + totalothertax);
              totalothertax= 0
            });                                                      did it your way, works like charm.

Comment: Nice! If you modify the interface as a result of the user interaction, consider delegating events, as @DoXicK suggested. "Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector, now or in the future"

Answer (score 0):

did you tried after putting your change binder statement outside click event handler?

```
$("#clonetax").click(function() {
        $("#newtaxrow:last").clone(true).insertAfter("#newtaxrow:last");
        $("#newtaxrow:last").find( ":input" ).val( "0" );
});
$("#newtaxrow:last").find( ":input" ).change(dave);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are selecting by #id (#newtaxrow) and clone that one.

you then have 2 rows with the same #id and it will only select the 1st #id. Every ID in a document is considered to be UNIQUE so there is no use to continue searching after the first one. It will always return only the first one it matches.

i've made an example here for you: http://jsfiddle.net/xZ8xX/

As you can see: it only gives 1 alert while there are 2 divs with id #row

try changing the

```
$('#newtaxrow') to $('.newtaxrow')
```

and then change from using 'newtaxrow' as an ID, to a CLASS. Or at least stop using 2 rows with the same ID :-)

Comment: almost right, but how do i use it for totaling the values of the cloned fields?

Comment: use LIVE events for the rows:
$('.newtaxrow :input').on('change', dave);
more on that here: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

You can not use same id for multiple elements. In your case use class selector instead of Id.

For example:

('.classname') instead of ('#idname') as suggested by @DoXicK